# INSERT (values) INTO two tables with foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have two tables in my database; EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT.

```
EMPLOYEE(Ssn, Name, Dno)

PK Ssn,
FK Dno REFERENCES Dnumber
```

*

```
DEPARTMENT(Dnumber, Dname, Mgr_ssn)

PK Dnumber,
FK Mgr_ssn REFERENCES Ssn
```

How can I insert values into two tables?

Ex.

```
EMPLOYEE('333445555', 'John', 5)
DEPARTMENT(5, 'Research', '333445555')
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You would insert into `department` first.  Is that your issue?

Comment: But Mgr_ssn is a foreign key that is not currently exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that it is acceptable situation that department may not have a menager for a period of time, so manager FK should be null-able.
On the side note using SSN as PK/FK is a bad practice, you should have this info protected and accessible on as needed basis. Use surrogate keys instead.

So steps:
1. INSERT department with NULL as manager
2. INSERT employee
3. UPDATE department manager